# How do Homelander's powers differ from Superman?

Tags: superman, the-boys, the-boys-2019

I've only watched the first three episodes of *The Boys* on Amazon Prime, but we have  Homelander who is an obvious analog to Superman.

As far as I recall, so far we've seen him employ:

- (presumably) super speed, strength, and longevity
- flight
- heat vision
- x-ray vision (blocked by lead, Superman; zinc, Homelander)
- super hearing

Not yet clear to me:

- Kryptonite equivalent
- ice breath
- anything to do with the yellow sun, etc.?

Is this accurate and are there any known differences between Homelander and Superman's classical powers?

Comment: Homelander's xray vision is blocked by zinc.  He says that when discussing the box for Translucent in episode 3.

Comment: @eshier, yes, I just noticed this on the episode I watched tonight.

Answer (score 5):

The primary difference is that Homelander was not born with his powers - he was created by the use of injecting the fetus with Compound V until their powers developed.

Due to this, the Vought Superheroes don't have "Weaknesses", like Superman and Kryptonite. And Homelander is at the pinnacle of the Vought American heroes. His powers are:

- Superhuman Strength
- Invulnerability
- Superhuman Speed
- X-Ray Vision (with the exception of objects/surfaces lined with zinc)
- Heat Vision
- Superhuman Hearing
- Flight

[Source](https://the-boys.fandom.com/wiki/Homelander)

The comic series also mentions longevity, similar to Captain America, but this is not mentioned in the show.

However, the theme of "The Boys" is that (most) superheroes are actually *not* the "good guys". They are more corrupt than most supervillains in any other series, because they are only "acting" like the good guys. They are in fact megalomaniacs, narcissists, or mentally twisted in one way or another. They do have "weaknesses", but only in the way that there are holes in their "defenses". Queen Maeve is severely depressed, A-Train is a drug addict, and Translucent is a deviant, as well as only being bulletproof on the outside.

Homelander, on the other hand, appears to only be fearful of Stillwell; the only thing that keeps him under control.

> However, this only lasts so long once he realises the truth about his creation, killing her and the series ending with him meeting his son - the offspring of one of his crimes.

However, if the comics are anything to go by (though certain events in the TV show have already diverted from this) as mentioned before, Homelander's mental state is his ultimate downfall

> In private, Homelander shows signs of approaching a mental breakdown, talking to his own reflection in a mirror and having bouts of nausea.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question on how his powers differ, just on how the characters differ.

Comment: @Theik yes, in an attempt to cover "weaknesses". These are more character specific, rather than something to do with their abilities, or specific items.

Comment: Your first paragraph should have a spoiler tag. It gives away the plot of the whole season.

Comment: They were all _born_ with powers.  Homelander may or may not have been conceived with them, but we don't really know.  Some were altered during gestation, but we are never told that they all are.  If he was, why is he raised by the corporation rather than his parents?  Likewise, we are never told where Compound V comes from originally, so it could be developed from studying Homelander's biology (in the show; I know how it was made in the comics).  There is a lot left open for further seasons.

Comment: @eshier all this is covered in the show. Homelander was the original one that they tested. His mother was killed during childbirth, and nothing is said of his father. There is also a scene where Billy finds an infant in a natal unit being injected with Compound V

Comment: @eshier They were not born this way, they were injected as babies. There is only one natural born super in the entire show so far, they are revealed as a cliffhanger in the very last episode and it's a big deal. The rest are all babies Vought injected after convincing their parents. (See Starlight's conversation with her mother.)

Answer (score 5):

## There are some differences...

Overall, superman's powers are stronger, but Homelander lacks a single weakness like Kryptonite for as far as we know.

Superman has been show to be able to freeze things with his breath or to blow people away; Homelander does not seem capable of these things.

Superman can lift massive objects even while flying, while Homelander claims he can't catch an airplane in the air because there's nothing to push off against. This might mean that Superman's flight generates more thrust.

Superman's super senses are vastly superior. Superman can hear and see things from miles away, Homelander stands basically next-to a wall to eavesdrop on Stillwell.

Superman can't see through lead, Homelander can't see through Zinc.

Superman has been shown to have speeds rivaling the Flash. Homelander's speed, while superhuman, does not seem anywhere near those levels.

It's currently unclear, but it's highly likely that Superman is vastly stronger than Homelander, has he's been shown to be capable of pushing even planets in the comics.

## but he's mostly the same

And that makes sense, because all the members of the Seven were pretty obvious copies of the Justice League.

- Homelander - Superman
- Queen Maeve - Wonder Woman
- A-Train - The Flash
- Black Noir - Batman
- The Deep - Aquaman
- Translucent - This one is a series-only invention, but the character he replaces (Jack from Jupiter) was a Martian Manhunter copy, and invisibility is one of the Martian Manhunter's powers.
- Starlight - A difficult one, but might be based on Doctor Light.

Comment: Not to forget, the Lamplighter with his Staff is presumably a copy of Green Lantern

Answer (score 0):

Subtle thing I noticed is that there does appear to be a way to suppress Supe powers.

Spoiler alert:

> When they recapture Kimiko, they make a point of showing you that they (Homelander's secret project team) inject her with something that appears to suppress her powers. When when the Boys go to rescue her, she appears to still be weak and suppressed after they take her off the chair.

I'm wondering it this will be played up in future episodes.

Comment: How does this apply to Homelander?   One assumes he could not be injected.

Comment: I mention it because it implies that there is a weakness of some sort. A "Kryptonite equivalent" as in the OP.